# How to call a PHP function from Angular 4

Tags: angular

How to call a PHP function from angular 4?
I have written the below code in my files and it returns nothing.

```
    .component.ts
constructor(private _server:ServerConnectService) {..}
    $('#fileUpload').on('click', (e)=>
            {
              this._server.uploadImage("Testing..").done((res)=>{ 
                console.log("uploadImage Response "+res); // I need a result->"PHP -> uploadImage() calling " and data here
              });
          });


    .service.ts
export class ServerConnectService {
uploadImageUrl:string = "http://localhost/toolapp/uploadImage.php";
constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { 
  }

    uploadImage(d){
        var myFunction = 'uploadImage';
        var data = {"data":d};
        return $.post(this.uploadImageUrl+"?action="+myFunction,data).then((res)=>{ return res; })
    }


    uploadImage.php
    <?php
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    function uploadImage($data){
        $res= "PHP -> uploadImage() calling ".$data;
        echo $res;
    }

    ?>
```

how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Guru

Comment: If you want to upload an image, a GET request is not the right method to do that. Use a PUT or POST request.

Comment: If you want to upload an image, a GET request is not the right method to do that. Use a PUT or POST request.

Comment: Hi Henry and Aron, thanks for your quick reply. Im sorry its post method. I have changed my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call HTTP get or post api and then you can use php function.

Comment: Hi Sachin, Thanks, for your reply. I have used POST method in that. and I have added "url?action=funcName". But its not calling the function in php. If I give echo "..."; before the function on the same .php page, its working. The only thing is function is not calling from angular 4. How to make it? How to use http post in that? Please help. Thanks, Guru

Comment: You can not access or call function from angular. You have to manage or call from php code.

Comment: Welcome @Guru. Let me know once it done or need any help

Comment: It's done calling like the below one.
in .service.ts
var callFunction = 'uploadImage';
    var data = {"data":d, "function":callFunction};
    return $.post(this.uploadImageUrl, data).done((res)=>{ return res; })

in PHP
$fn = $_POST["function"];

 if($fn == "uploadImage"){
    $da = $_POST["data"];
    uploadImage($da);
 } else if($fn == "uploadDummy"){
    uploadDummy();
 }
function uploadImage($datas){
    $res= "PHP -> uploadImage() calling ".$datas;
    echo $res;
}

function uploadDummy(){
    echo "uploadDummy() calling...";
}

Answer (score 1):

Angular is not server side rendered and hence the following code will not be parsed by the php engine to generate the required javascript. You will have to expose a REST API with POST interface that accepts the image as a file or `base64` encoded string.

Then using Angular HttpClientModule or HttpModule you can send the image to the appropriate service.